# Support DXF file WordPress

Tags: wordpress, file, file-upload, upload, media-library

I found this code to support `.dwg` files in the WordPress media library.

```
function custom_upload_mimes ( $existing_mimes=array() ) {
    $existing_mimes['dwg'] = 'image/vnd.dwg';
    return $existing_mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_upload_mimes');
```

What do I need to add to support `.dxf` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function add_dxf_support($mimes) {
    $mimes['dxf'] = 'application/dxf';
    return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes','add_dxf_support');
```

Comment: Worked for me, this plugin will help some people who need other file types:
https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-extra-file-types/